# search pattern in database table

Tags: sql, regex, database, pattern-matching

I need to search sentences with predefined patterns and get results if matched. Let's say i have a million record of pre-defined patterns like a*b*, ab*cd* ... in a table. How can achieve this, is there any database engine which can search like below ?

My sentence is:  "come home"
And table has 2 columns : ID,PATTERN

Table has 2 Rows Data:

1, c* h

2, b* h* ( you can think b[a-z]* h[a-z]* in different format)

So when i query "come home" from table it should return me id=1 because that resembles c*h* pattern.

Appreciate any clue or help
Best Regards

Answer (score 2):

I don't know of a database system that will do this efficiently.  But, it is easy enough to implement in SQL:

```
select t.*
from table t
where 'come home' like t.pattern;
```

For `like`, you need to use the right wildcards, so in your particular example:

```
select t.*
from table t
where 'come home' like replace(t.pattern, '*', '%');
```